# Ubuntu DNS Error Chrome: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN, Firefox similar

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, dns

I am unable to visit most sites online in either firefox or chrome. I can access google docs so I am researching on windows 7 (dualboot) and rebooting into Ubuntu (recently upgraded to 16.04).

Test 0:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean
$
```

(nothing happened)

Test 1:

```
$ dig microsoft.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> microsoft.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2944
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;microsoft.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
microsoft.com.      896 IN  A   104.43.195.251
microsoft.com.      896 IN  A   23.100.122.175
microsoft.com.      896 IN  A   23.96.52.53
microsoft.com.      896 IN  A   191.239.213.197
microsoft.com.      896 IN  A   104.40.211.35

;; Query time: 102 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:558:feed::1#53(2001:558:feed::1)
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 29 14:54:43 EDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122
```

Test 2:

```
$ ping reddit.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Test 3:

```
$ less /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Test 4:

```
$ less /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
/#dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=D4:BE:D9:A6:2E:C1,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Test 5: Chrome

> This site can’t be reached
>   www.reddit.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
>
> ```
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
> ```

Test 6: Firefox

> Server not found
>   Firefox can’t find the server at www.reddit.com.
>   Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
>   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
>   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Edit: Almost forgot, this seems to have started after I tried installing PlayOnLinux the other day. I uninstalled it but the problems persist.

Any thoughts?

Re: possible duplicate question : dns_probe_finished_nxdomain error caused by Ubuntu
[dns_probe_finished_nxdomain error caused by Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844785/dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-error-caused-by-ubuntu)
I clearly state in my question that the solution posed in the other thread of clearing the dns cache does not resolve my issue.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/844785/dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-error-caused-by-ubuntu poses a similar issue, but the resolution proposed there does not fix the issue. My attempt to use the solution from that thread is listed as test 0 in my question, and it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Related?: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1647031

Comment: nekketsuuu I think the bug you linked is related, but it did not provide a solution for me. I actually moved over the weekend and now am able to use a wired connection and that is working fine, so the problem is with wireless only and I'm not going to spend any more time on it for now. If anyone else knows exactly what's going on and wants me to test a fix I'd be happy to though.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### Resolved: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in Linux

---

**Step 1.**   Open terminal and add below command

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

**Step 2.** Now add below line in file

```
supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
```

Now, **save file**

**Step 3.** Restart the network

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

**or**

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Refresh your page and done.

Comment: Really solved (!)... What the possible **cause?**  A trojan? An UBUNTU upgrade?

Comment: Nope, I'm unlucky one

Comment: This solved the issue for me but it would be nice to have this solution explained... what `supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;` does?

Comment: solved here too :) @AndreaVacondio it sets your DNS to Google's public DNS

Comment: Does not work for me. Kubuntu 20.04 going over a Netgear range extender. Normal Router has no problems to begin with.

Comment: Accepted this answer as it looks like others were helped by it.

Comment: not working for ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Works like a charm !! anyone please explain...

Comment: for ubuntu 20.04 run below command
`
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
`
If above does not work run 
`
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
`

Add below name servers to file and refresh the page will work fine.
`
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 4.2.2.2
`

Answer (score 6):

For me (Ubuntu 20.04), the only working solution was to add DNS servers of Google and OpenDNS.

I did it **at computer level**:

```
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

And added these lines (before other nameservers):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

To make these changes **permanent**, follow this: [how to change DNS server permanently on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280277/how-to-change-dns-server-permanently-on-ubuntu-20-04)

This can be also done **at router level** (for all devices):

- Go to router management -> DNS -> Set primary DNS to 8.8.8.8 and secondary DNS to 208.67.222.222.

See https://linuxhint.com/opendns-vs-googledns/ for more info about choosing the DNS nameservers (and checking which server is faster in your location).

Comment: It works! For some reason I had only: nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: Well: The file is dynamic (generated by systemd-resolved) so you *loose* your change! For some reason I only have: nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: for ubuntu 20.04 it's working fine. Thanks @Filip Kunbicz

Comment: Working for ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: To make this change permanent, you can install `resolvconf` as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280277/how-to-change-dns-server-permanently-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 4):

For me it was flushing the `dns cache` that way:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

You can then check the statistics in order to make sure that your cache size is now zero.

```
sudo systemd-resolve --statistics
```

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the router solved this problem for me.

Comment: I know the asker said they did not experience that problem on windows so you might assume the problem can only be solved on the ubuntu system, but I only experienced the problem on one browser and not on another, and still restarting the router solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue.
I have tried everything from all answers and none of these work for me.
I am working right now on something which requires a lot of DNS updates and this completely blocks my work all the time. I have to go and look at the site on my phone / ipad to see if it is really working.

Is there any other possible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it from TpLink router -admin panel settings.

Go to `Advance` > `Network` > `LAN settings`, and change:

`Primary DNS` : 8.8.8.8

`Secondary DNS` : 8.8.4.4

Hit save then restart your router, wait to see your internet indicator lights up on your router and then reload your pages to check.